# Languages and Grammar (Finding a language)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

I have a trivial question (that I have actually solved, hopefully) although I am a bit curious if my result is alright.

We have $N= \{S , C ,D\}$, $T=\{c, d\}$ and $P = \{S \to Dc, D \to Dd, D \to Cd, C \to Cc, C \to c\}$

I have tried this and my answer for this is $L(G)= c^{m+1} d^{m+1} c$, for $m \geq 0$.

So there was a friend of mine and we talked about this, and he told me that he could create the word $cdddc$, and he told me that he was very sure about it!!! I really think that he is wrong, because from my $L(G)$ it isn't possible to create this word!!

Opinions?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: $S \to \underline{D}c \: [D \to Dd] \to \underline{D}dc \: [D \to Dd] \to \underline{D}ddc \: [D \to Cd] \to \underline{C}dddc \: [C \to c] \to cdddc$

Comment: @user35603 Hmmm indeed. So my formula is wrong. But I guess it could work, if instead of c^(m+1) put something like c^(n+1). Right?

Comment: @Agnes: Yes, I think you're right, $L(G)=\{ c^nd^mc : m,n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Comment: @user35603 Yes but the way you have written it now it is wrong, because if n,m=0 then it is just c. For n,m=0 it should be c which is not possible.

Comment: Assuming that $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,...\}$.

Comment: alright I see it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following productions:

$$\begin{align*}
&S\to Dc\\
&D\to Dd\mid Cd\\
&C\to Cc\mid c
\end{align*}$$

Clearly any derivation must begin $S\Rightarrow Dc$. You can now apply the production $D\to Dd$ any non-negative number of times; if you apply it $n$ times, you have

$$S\Rightarrow Dc\Rightarrow^n Dd^nc\;.$$

Eventually, however, you must apply $D\to Cd$, in order to reach a terminal word:

$$S\Rightarrow Dc\Rightarrow^n Dd^nc\Rightarrow Cd^{n+1}c\;.$$

Now you can apply $C\to Cc$ any non-negative number of times, followed by $C\to c$, at which point the derivation must cease. Suppose that you apply $C\to Cc$ $m$ times; then your derivation is

$$S\Rightarrow Dc\Rightarrow^n Dd^nc\Rightarrow Cd^{n+1}c\Rightarrow^m Cc^md^{n+1}c\Rightarrow c^{m+1}d^{n+1}c\;.$$

In other words, $$L(G)=\{c^md^nc:m,n\ge 1\}\;,$$ the set of words consisting of a string of one or more $c$’s followed by a string of one or more $d$’s followed by a single $c$. A regular expression corresponding to this language is $cc^*dd^*c$; if you use extended regular expressions and allow the plus operator, you can write it $c^+d^+c$.

In particular, $cdddc\in L(G)$.

Your description of $L(G)$ implies that the productions $D\to Dd$ and $C\to Cc$ are applied the same number of times, which need not be the case. In fact, your language is a context-free language that is not regular, while your grammar is definitely a regular grammar.

Comment: Thanks, it was quite informative. BUT in the end, if I just say that L(G)= $$c^{m+1}d^{n+1}c : m,n >=0 \;.$$  It is still correct, isn't it ?

Comment: @Agnes: Yes, it is. You could even use $$\{c^{m-1}d^{n-2}c:m\ge 2\text{ and }n\ge 3\}\;,$$ though it would be a horribly silly thing to do. Anything that gives you every positive number of $c$’s in the initial string and, independently, every positive number of $d$’s in the middle string works fine.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I can see your point.

Comment: @Agnes: You’re welcome.